# OpenXml SDK- How to uniquely identify a paragraph in a word document

Tags: openxml-sdk

I need to extract paragraphs based on some unique ids or something that can identify/differentiate each paragraph in a 50- 60 pages word document (using TX Text Editor to load it) . I will tag these unique identification to a list box or some other list control and on-click of the list box item, go to that specific paragraph and highlight it. I thought w:paraID is unique but it is null and not for development purpose. There should be some custom hack where in i can add something.

Right now i convert the TxText Editor loaded content to docx -> wordprocessingML and trying to figure out how to extract certain paragraphs using some unique ids or style. The Content of the Paragraph will not be known, only some mapping between the listitem and Docx will be there to highlight the entire paragraph.

Regards,
Jasbir

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do this. The best way will depend on the circumstances.

1. You could address each paragraph by its positional index. If your document contains `N` paragraphs, the first one would be at index `0` and the last one at index `N-1`. This solution does not require any markup.
2. If you can pre-process the Word document, you can add either "**permanent**" or "**ignorable**" markup to identify each paragraph uniquely:

   - "**Permanent**" markup means markup that will not be removed by Microsoft Word. There are at least two solutions:

     - You can add `w:bookmarkStart` and `w:bookmarkEnd` elements (using the `BookmarkStart` and `BookmarkEnd` instances) around your paragraphs. The `w:name` attribute of the `w:bookmarkStart` element can serve as your unique id.
     - You can enclose each `w:p` element (`Paragraph` instances) in a `w:sdt` (block-level structured document tag) element. A `w:sdt` element (`SdtBlock` instance) can have a `w:sdtPr` child element (`SdtProperties` instance), which can have a `w:tag` child element (`Tag` instance). The `w:val` attribute value of the `w:tag` element can serve as your unique id.
   - "**Ignorable**" markup means markup that can be removed by Microsoft Word if you open and re-save the document. For example, you can define your own XML namespace, declare that in the `w:document` root element (`Document` instance), and add this to the list of `mc:Ignorable` namespace prefixes. Then, you can add attributes prefixed with your namespace to the `w:p` elements (`Paragraph` instances). Your attribute value can be the unique id.

So, say you have the following document (with simplified markup):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">First paragraph.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Second paragraph.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Using `w:bookmarkStart` and `w:bookmarkEnd` elements, your marked-up document looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="1" w:name="UniqueId_1" />
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">First paragraph.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1" />
    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="2" w:name="UniqueId_2" />
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Second paragraph.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="2" />
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

With `w:sdt` elements, your document would look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:sdt>
      <w:sdtPr>
        <w:tag w:val="UniqueId_1" />
      </w:sdtPr>
      <w:sdtContent>
        <w:p>
          <w:r>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">First paragraph.</w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:p>
      </w:sdtContent>
    </w:sdt>
    <w:sdt>
      <w:sdtPr>
        <w:tag w:val="UniqueId_2" />
      </w:sdtPr>
      <w:sdtContent>
        <w:p>
          <w:r>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">Second paragraph.</w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:p>
      </w:sdtContent>
    </w:sdt>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Finally, using ignorable markup, your document could look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:my="http://my.domain.com/some/url/for/my/namespace"            
            mc:Ignorable="my">
  <w:body>
    <w:p my:uniqueId="UniqueId_1">
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">First paragraph.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p my:uniqueId="UniqueId_2">
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Second paragraph.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Using the paragraph index would be the most straightforward solution. Next, adding ignorable markup requires only one additional attribute per paragraph. However, this attribute will not survive if you open and save the document with Microsoft Word. Next, the bookmarks are a pretty non-intrusive solution for the end-user. However, bookmarks are harder to process. Finally, `w:sdt` elements are straightforward to create in a pure-functional transformation, and they are easy to process later on. However, they might get into the way of your end-users if you want them to continue working with the Word document.